# Can't run/publish azure functions on VS 2017 15.8.5 for .net standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0

I cannot run Azure Functions anymore. When I try to debug it, an error message appears:

"A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly".

But I just created a brand new Azure Function project and tried to run (I didn't change any code or property).

If I try to publish the Azure Function, there's no option to deploy it to the cloud, only for a local folder. The option to publish it to the cloud is missing.

I've already uninstalled Visual Studio and installed back again. I think there's a problem with the latest updates. Here is the info of my installation. Does anyone has any ideia what I can do?

---

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.8.5
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.5+28010.2036
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Professional

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017 15.8.05085.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services 15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017 5.2.60618.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0 15.8.05023.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 15.9.02009.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Common Azure Tools 1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft Azure Tools 2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - v2.9.10730.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on updating the package "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" to version 1.0.22.

If you revert the version to 1.0.14 it works.

Is it a problem on Visual Studio or there's some config we can setup to fix that?

Comment: Looking in to this.  Will post an update when I have more info.

Comment: I cannot repro this issue with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.8.6. Can you please update and try?

Comment: Same Problem here with VS 15.8.6 and 1.0.22. Going back to 1.0.21 also helped.